# To display an imagebutton over a VideoView while video is Playing

Tags: android, video

To display an image button over a video for 3-6 seconds while the video is playing.I tried doing with handler(post delayed method) ,it works fine first time,but when we seek back the video then it wont display the button.So I tried using the thread,but now the problem is that button onclick is not working.

```
     public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){

 if(position == 0){

      mediaPlayer.start();

     if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
     }
       }else{
             videoView.seekTo((int) position);
             videoView.start();
         }
         Thread t = new Thread() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     while (!isInterrupted()) {
                         Thread.sleep(1000);
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 text.setText(String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                                String input = text.getText().toString();
                                  inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                                 if(inputValue >= 3000 && inputValue <= 6000){
                                     imagebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                     imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View view) {


                                             stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition(); //stopPosition is an int
                                             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewClass.class);
                                             intent.putExtra("key", messsage);
                                             intent.putExtra("intVariableName", stopPosition);
                                             startActivity(intent);

                                         }
                                     });
                                 }else{
                                     imagebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 }
                             }
                         });

                     }
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 }
             }

         };

 t.start();
  }
```

});

It is moving to WebViewClass.class but then it crashes.

### D/libGLESv2: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.sample.u51434.video D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1 E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4291 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.sample.u51434.video, PID: 4291 java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method) at com.sample.u51434.video.MainActivity$1$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:100) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4291 SIG: 9 Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: post the logcat containing the crash log...

Comment: below is the crash log.Thanks